# Clojure and noir for a classic web application

Tags: clojure, noir

How would one go about using Noir with user authentication and an ORM.

Would it all have to be accessed via java objects?

Are there any rails style "blog" tutorials that go about user auth and database access?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/ibdknox/Noir-blog. It uses a [simple file-based db](https://github.com/aboekhoff/congomongo), but it shouldn't be too hard to replace it with for example MongoDB using [CongoMongo](https://github.com/aboekhoff/congomongo), or a different one.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small noir-based webapp which lists the contents of an 'users' table from MySQL using the [korma library](http://sqlkorma.com). It's pretty simple but you can check it here: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/noir-showdate